# Pandas rank valus in rows of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

Learning Python. I have a dataframe like this

```
     cand1    cand2    cand3
0    40.0900  39.6700  36.3700
1    44.2800  44.2800  35.4200
2    43.0900  51.2200  46.3500
3    35.7200  55.2700  36.4700
```

and I want to rank each row according to the value of the columns, so that I get

```
     cand1    cand2    cand3
0    1        2        3
1    1        1        3
2    1        3        2
3    3        1        2
```

I have now

```
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc['Rank'] = df.loc[index].rank(ascending=False).astype(int)
        print (df)
```

However, this keeps on repeating the whole dataframe. Note also the special case in row 2, where two values are the same.

Suggestion appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `df.rank` instead of series `rank`

```
df_rank = df.rank(axis=1, ascending=False, method='min').astype(int)

Out[165]:
   cand1  cand2  cand3
0      1      2      3
1      1      1      3
2      3      1      2
3      3      1      2
```